# Using mat-dialog but not display correctly

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-7

This is my page.
[image: my page]

And when I click the heart button I will get this mat-dialog but it have some issue about display.

[image: Display issue]

This is my icon code.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Action">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                 ...
                <span>
                  <mat-icon (click)="openDialog()" svgIcon="favorite_plus"></mat-icon>
                </span>
              </td>
            </ng-container>
```

This is my function to open mat-dialog.

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

    openDialog(): void {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PopupAddOrdersWishListComponent, {
            height: '600px',
            width: '800px'
        });
    }
```

This is scss file for popup component

```
.example-card-full-width {
    width: 95%;
}

.mat-radio-button~.mat-radio-button {
    margin-left: 16px;
}

.pt-5,
.py-5 {
    padding-top: 1rem !important;
}

.card-title,
.cart-table__column,
.btn {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.highlight {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.address-card__row,
.content {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.cart__checkout-button {
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    .cart__checkout-button {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
}

.responsive-size {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I try to comment any css one by one but its not work for me.

Comment: can you share a minimal stackblitz so that we can see the issue in action and help

Comment: Can you describe what the issue is? Two arrows on a picture does not give enough information.

Comment: Ok I will add more pic

Comment: @wnvko
Picture is edited.

Comment: your dashboard is in a container that fills the viewport and what i see from photos is that when you open the dialog that containers height changes somehow. it seems to be a css issue. it is difficult to elaborate. Can you add css file for PopupAddOrdersWishListComponent? And do you have any global styles set for PopupAddOrdersWishListComponent or MatDialog?

Comment: @ysf okay, you got it.

Comment: well, i don't see any issue with PopupAddOrdersWishListComponent css. can you create a stackblitz? because there is nothing else i can think of, sorry :)